# Get the first image src from a post in django

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I have a model to write blogs. In that I'm using a wysiwyg editor for the `Blog`'s `descritpion`,  through which I can insert an image within the `description`.

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True)
    description = models.TextField()
    pubdate = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    publish = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

In the admin it looks like this:

[image]

What I want is to get first image inside the description of the blog, and present it in the template like this:

[image]

How do get the `img` `src` from the description of the blog to use it in the template? Your help and guidance will be very much appreciated. Thank you.

views.py:

```
def blog(request):
    blogs = Blog.objects.all()

    return render(request, 'blogs.html', {
        'blogs':blogs
        })
```

template:

```
  {% for blog in blogs %}
  <div class="blog">
      <p class="blog_date"> {{blog.pubdate}} </p>
      <h2 class="blog_title"> {{blog.title}} </h2>
      <img src="{{STATIC_URL}} ###img src to be included" class="blog_image img-responsive img-thumbnail">


          <a href="blog_detail.html" class="blog_read_more btn btn-info">Read more</a>
      <div class="container">
          <p class="divider">***</p>
      </div>
  </div>
  {% endfor %}
```

Comment: what's the name of your wysiwyg editor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a **basic approach** you can tweak for your convenience:

Add a first_image field to your model:

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True)
    description = models.TextField()
    pubdate = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    publish = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    first_image = models.CharField(max_length=400, blank=True)
```

Now all you have to do is populate your first_image field on save, so your model's save method should look like this:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    # This regex will grab your first img url
    # Note that you have to use double quotes for the src attribute
    img = re.search('src="([^"]+)"'[4:], self.description)
    self.first_image = img.group().strip('"')
    super(Blog, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Now simply reference it in your template.

**This is not a fully fledged solution**, there are other things that you should take into account, like differentiating between a smiley or thumbnail or a code snippet imr src and an actual img src, but this should do for personal use, you don't want to limit other people's choice to having their first image as the cover image.

Hope this helps!

Comment: if you mean calling the .update() method, then no, it won't update the field since .update() doesn't call the save method. look at the docs for a solution to this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#update

Comment: This will update the blog with the first_image every time you call the .save() method, for .update() look above.

Comment: I tried doing that, but its showing no image link. The first_image is blank.

Comment: it should work now, just change the URLField to CharField to pass the url validation constraint, since in this case you're not grabbing a full url.

Comment: i did that too... I think, its not saving first_image.

Comment: i have a similar working example, but with super() at the bottom of the save() method, so i tried placing it at the top and it stopped working! last thing to try is to place the super() method at the end of the save() method, because the new first_image is not being passed to it, please tell me if it works.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would parse the HTML when receiving a post for a new blog to get the image source, and store it to the data-base (with a specific field), so that you do not need to do it afterwards.

I guess that the description is in HTML, in which case you could derive a class from `HTMLParser`, and implement the `handle_starttag` method so that you store the source of the first image you get (And a default image otherwise).